# Simulink s-function builder

Tags: simulink, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to link a raspberry pi 2 with a Wiimote using Simulink and Wiiuse libraries (written in C and compiled for x64).

I have created an s-function using the builder, added the code and the libraries (i.e. wiiuse.dll, wiiuse.exp wiiuse.lib) on the libraries tab.

The model executes correctly on my PC, but when I executed as external on the raspberry I get this:

```
./wiiuse.lib: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the Wiiuse libraries compiled for the Raspberry Pi OS?

Comment: I am new to simulink but for what I know the library (i.e. .lib file) need to be x64. Simulink should to the rest, knowing the hardware tarjet, raspberry in this case. I was unable to find any useful documentation, only the description on mathworks webpage.